# how are the openings in the Whitney $C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m})$ topology

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am studying whitney topology in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the definition says:

1. let's consider $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m})$.
2. Let $k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, the we denote $M(U)=\lbrace f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m}):j^{k}f(\mathbb{R}^{n})\subset U\rbrace$.

The set  $\lbrace M(U):k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\rbrace$, where $U\subset J^{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m})$,
forms a basis for a topology.

Where $j^{k}f(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, is the Taylor expansion to order k.

The definition confuses me a bit, I am not sure if the openings in this topology are jets, which are Taylor expansions, I have tried to give an example, I could not
I have thought about considering functions that are equal at a point within the Taylor polynomial, but I am not sure

Comment: You want to allow the values of the function and its first $k$ derivatives (partials of order up to $k$) to vary in some open sets.

Comment: @TedShifrin 
I'm a bit confused, I'm not sure if the open ones in this topology are the k-jets?

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense to me.

Comment: @TedShifrin, 
Suddenly I am not very clear, my question, what are the openings in the whitney topology?

Comment: I told you this in my first comment. Maybe you need to read more sources.

Comment: @TedShifrin, 
I have not found much information about it, I tried to fill the Hirsch, I did not find much, if it is not too much trouble, could you recommend an article or book